# problems while generating java code from jruby

Tags: jruby

I have problems while generating .java files with jruby 1.7.3. Here is an example:

```
class Duck
    def quack()
        puts "quack!";
    end
end
def quack_it(duck)
    duck.quack
end
a = Duck.new
quack_it(a)
```

when I execute

`jrubyc --java Test.rb` I get the following compilation error:

```
Failure during compilation of file DuckExample_simple.rb:
undefined method `new_method' for nil:NilClass.
```

Therefore, I have 2 questions:

1. What is wrong here?
2. I want to generate .java files in order to see how the JRuby code is translated into the bytecode and instead of reading the bytecode itself I thought to read the java code. Does the generated java code correspond 1 to 1 to the bytecode generated by AOT jruby compiler, or it's better to read the bytecode itself? I actually want to see how jruby handles dynamic method dispatch at the bytecode level. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't use jruby so i am not really the best guy to talk to, but here are my 2 cents anyways.

if you just put a simple class into the file, it will work. so try

```
class Duck
  def quack()
    puts "quack!"
  end
end
```

it will create a `Duck.java` file as you would expect, which answeres the second question you had. there is also a nice writeup about the generated file here: http://rhnh.net/2012/10/20/guice-in-your-jruby

i guess that the command is somewhat broken. it would be best to open an issue at the jruby issue tracker: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY

Comment: Not sure if there is actually a bug here, but the bug tracker is now officially Github: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/ (See JRuby 1.7.5 announcement: http://jruby.org/2013/10/07/jruby-1-7-5.html)

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec thx, i just picked the first google result :) from what i read, it should compile any ruby script, but it fails.

Comment: No worries, it's only official since yesterday. ;)